# Scanning OCR on a Zebra TC52 with an Android firemonkey Delphi application

Tags: android, delphi, ocr, zebra-scanners

I'm developing an Android application with Embarcadero RAD Studio 11 to deploy on a Zebra TC52.
I'm trying to activate the OCR scanner by clicking a button on a screen.

I have to read a 10 character number on a document. I tried to read about the zembra documentation but I couldn't find the bees to call in the intent

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Please provide more details: which Android version is installed? Did you successfully deploy and run a Delphi app to the device? Does the TC52 documentation include example code (written in Java) you can share here?

Comment: I've done something that uses the SDK direct here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/SymbolScanner